# What is the cause of compilation error in my code

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am running asp.net, C#4.0 application in VS2010. I get the following compilation error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: ASPNET: Make sure that the class defined in this code file matches the 'inherits' attribute, and that it extends the correct base class (e.g. Page or UserControl).

Source Error:

Line 1:  using System;

Line 2:  using System.Collections.Generic;

Line 3:  using System.Linq;
```

My page attribute is :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs"
    EnableEventValidation="false" Inherits="jsPlumb_jsPlumb_Default2" %>
```

my c#codebehind class:

```
  namespace CompanyDisplay.jsPlumb.jsPlumb.jsPlumb
  {
        public  class jsPlumb_jsPlumb_Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
    }
}
```

i want namespace to present for running some webservice applications.

Comment: Show your code ... in order to get more help.

Comment: Add some code to explain your issue.

Comment: which code .cs code?it says the error is on default.aspx.cs line 1:using System Source File: d:\CompanyDisplay\CompanyDisplay\CompanyDisplay\jsPlumb\jsPlumb\jsPlumb\Default2.aspx.cs    Line: 1

Comment: Start from:what did you add and this error appear ?

Comment: i added namespace to this file default2.aspx.cs as CompanyDisplay.jsPlumb.jsPlumb.jsPlumb

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this :

1. add batch=”false” in the compilation tag of your applications web.config file as shown below

   **compilation debug=”true” batch=”false”**
2. clean solution
3. delete the temporary files folder in Visual Studio(the folder which it shows in the exception)
4. do an iisreset and the rebuild my code again

Comment: and maybe re-install windows ? I do not think that you can define a solution with out understand the problem

Comment: anyway - why not? just try it!

Answer (score 0):

This error shows up when code-behind class name doesn't match "inherits" attribute on your aspx page. Maybe you tried to rename something?

Furthermore, I've seen this error, when you try to view a new page, but didn't compile the source, so even though your aspx exists, it can't fight the corresponding code-behind class.

**Edit:**

You have a completely messed up naming conventions, no surprise you're having troubles to match class names properly.

Sorry, but this is just preposterous!

```
inherits="CompanyDisplay.jsPlumb.jsPlumb.jsPlumb.jsPlumb_jsPlumb_Default2"
```

Fix your conventions and maybe you find yourself having source files like this:

```
CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyNamespace.jsPlumb.Default"
```

Don't do it like jsPlumb.jsPlumb.jsPlumb....That's just a nightmare!

Comment: @jeni, don't just "try", it's a pretty straightforward thing. If it didn't help, show us these things - PAGE attributes of your aspx file, class name of code-behind and class name of auto-generated code-behind. (those first lines starting like "public class Something : Page")

Comment: I edit my question , have added page attribute and c# codebehind class..please see it

Answer (score 0):

I got the ANSWER ; I should give the inherit attribute as;

inherits="CompanyDisplay.jsPlumb.jsPlumb.jsPlumb.jsPlumb_jsPlumb_Default2"

Comment: we should add the namespace so that onlt the aspx page will inherit the proper class in cs page please refer;http://forums.asp.net/t/941553.aspx/1

Comment: this problem appears only if you naming with the same name, too many thinks, that this is not good design. I have thousandth of pages and never have this issue.